# Do I still need to use third party gem for localized URI in rail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

In the past we need to use other module such as https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing, is it still the prefer case now?

I just want some basic URI mapping, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/users/1 (default)
http://www.example.com/es/users/1 
http://www.example.com/jp/users/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

You can set the locale prefix like this.

```
 scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de|hr/ do
    get "foo/bar"
  end
```

This matches:

- `/foo/bar`
- `/en/foo/bar`
- `/de/foo/bar`
- `/hr/foo/bar`